# How to prove two multivariate functions have the same minimas and maximas?

Tags: vector-analysis

If we have two multivariate functions $f(\boldsymbol{x})$ and $g(\boldsymbol{x})$, where $\boldsymbol{x}$ is a vector, how to prove they have the same minimas and maximas? The first intuitive solution come to my mind is to calculate the dot product of their gradients, i.e., $$\langle \nabla f(\boldsymbol{x}), \nabla g(\boldsymbol{x})\rangle.$$ I think if the dot products are larger than $0$, the two functions may have the same minimas and maximas. Does that make any sense? If yes, how to explain it? If no, is there any other solutions?